# eigenvector perturbation

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the proof of Theorem 1 of (http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/ijcai01-linkanalysis.pdf), the authors cite a theorem from Steward and Sun (Theorem V.2.8) which states that if $S$ is symmetric and $(\lambda^*, a^*)$ is the principle eigenvector/value pair, then some eigenpair $(\lambda, a)$ for $S + E$ with $E$ symmetric satisfies the following conditions:

$\| a^* - a\| \leq 4 \| E \|_F / (\delta - \sqrt{2} \| E \|_F)$

$| \lambda^* - \lambda | \leq \sqrt{2} \| E \|_F$.

I cannot find this reference online-- can anybody help me sketch a proof of this?